# Composer Error While upgrading magento version 2.1.6 to 2.2.2

Tags: magento2, composer, magento-upgrade

I am trying to upgrade the magento version from 2.1.6 to 2.2.2. I am using composer to upgrade the version.

I have used below commands

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 --no-update
composer update
```

Also I have already removed the "escapesshellarg" from the disable_function string but still I am getting below Error

```
[ErrorException]
escapeshellarg() has been disabled for security reasons
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is an issue  php setting. You need to enable it  **escapesshellarg**.

```
php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
```

I searched `escapesshellarg`, and found it in `disable_functions=`. I deleted it from `disable_functions` and that fixed it.

Comment: I have already follow these steps but didn't get any success